# Why does my app send one email then no more?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

Simple app to send an email when '/email' is requested.
Once deployed it sends one email when either '/' or '/email' then will send no further emails.
I think I have a basic misconception about how code runs on GAE.

Main.py

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import mail
count = 0 #to see how variables work
MyEmail = mail.EmailMessage(sender="IFG Cloud <ValidSender@gmail.com>",
                            subject="IFG Test Email")

MyEmail.to = "MyEmail@gmail.com>"
MyEmail.body = """IFG Test Message"""


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    count += 1
    def get(self):

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('IFG Texting App.  Message test. ') #This works
        self.response.write(count) #count does not += 1, why? Do I need to use datastore?


class EmailWill(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    MyEmail.send() #This sends one email when you got to URL '/' or '/email' then upon refresh it sends no more.
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Sending Email to wwelker@gmail.com') #This works



application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/email', EmailWill),                                   

], debug=True)
```

app.yaml

```
application: ifgalert
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: Main.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
```

I have successfully gone through the GAE tutorials on Goggle's site but I would love to find tutorials that go beyond that.  I have found many that are out dated and give me piles of hopeless errors when trying to run.
Using Eclipse with Pydev.  Launching with GAE Launcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MyEmail.send()` line is in the body of the class definition, not within any function. So it gets executed when the class is declared, not when it is actually instantiated to an object or when `get()` is called.

I'd create `MyEmail` and send it under the `get()` function:

```
class EmailWill(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        MyEmail = mail.EmailMessage(
                        sender="IFG Cloud <ValidSender@gmail.com>",
                        subject="IFG Test Email")
        MyEmail.to = "MyEmail@gmail.com>"
        MyEmail.body = """IFG Test Message"""
        MyEmail.send()
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Sending Email to wwelker@gmail.com') #This works
```